# Inconsistent AlarmManager performance

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I need my activity to stay on top no matter what happens in the device. So one of the mechanisms to ensure it working is also using the `AlarmManager`.

But it doesn't behave consistently across devices: the original intended tablet running Android 4.2. works as expected. Emulator running the same Android version only triggers the alarm once and then stops. Android 5.x doesn't trigger the alarm at all.

There are no messages in logcat indicating any problem with this setup.

Code to add AlarmManager entry:

```
void runCheckTop(boolean create)
{
  String TOP_CHECK = ".TOP_CHECK";
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  String action = getPackageName() + TOP_CHECK;
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, new Intent(action), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
  log.i("kiosk mode", "setting AlarmManager entry '%s'", action);

  if (create)
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 500, intent);
  else
    alarmManager.cancel(intent);
}
```

The receiver:

```
public class SIPIncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    log.e("Incoming receiver intent", intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getAction().equals(context.getPackageName() + MainActivity.TOP_CHECK))
    {
      //Notify the activity as well
      context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(context.getPackageName() + MainActivity.TOP_CHECK + "A"));
      //Get top running process
      String topAct = new TopRunningProcess().get("");
      log.i("TopCheck", "%s %s %b", topAct, context.getPackageName(), topAct.equals(context.getPackageName()));
      if (!topAct.equals(context.getPackageName()))
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Activity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or did I just miss a memo which says that AlarmManager shouldn't be used for intervals so short after API 19?

Answer (score 1):

> did I just miss a memo which says that AlarmManager shouldn't be used for intervals so short after API 19?

Yes, well, I'm not sure there was a memo about this, but the minimum interval is now `60000`. If you specify a number less than that, android studio will report:

[image]

Reference in code can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/AlarmDetector.java), I have not found a documentation page referencing this other than this snippet:

> To reduce abuse, there are restrictions on how frequently these alarms will go off for a particular application. Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched);

from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Comment: Oh, thanks. I remember seeing this warning before. The problem is, though, that the alarm doesn't trigger even after 60 seconds. Even if I set it to 60 seconds (vs letting it be overridden).

Comment: Have you verified `create` is set to true

Comment: `if (create)` statement

Comment: oh, that one is true whenever kiosk mode is set to on, so yes, it's on. I have multiple visual indicators about it being on, so there's little chance that I'd miss that one